# How to pass javascript/jQuery script in dsp param tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, atg

I am using `ATG` and I'm passing `dsp include` tags, where inside I'm passing `dsp param` tags

```
<div id="page1">
    <span id="nameVal"></span>
    <dsp:include page="/name.jsp">
        <dsp:param name="age" value="${currentAGE}" />
        <dsp:param name="name" value="" />
    </dsp:include>
</div>
```

and In my `jQuery`file, I am writing as -

```
if($("#page1").length > 0){
    $('#nameVal').text('akshay');
}
```

I want to access the nameVal value which I'm getting from jQuery in `<dsp:param name="name" value="" />` as soon as my `page1` div loads.

If the dsp include tags can be accessed after the page load and then access the data it can also work. Please help.

Comment: So, you want a selector to access `<dsp:param name="name" value="" />`?

Comment: @JuanScolari I want to pass the javascript value in the `dsp param tag`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting by the name attribute and setting the value with `val()`:

```
if($("#page1").length > 0){
    $('#page1 [name="name"]').val('akshay');
}
```